# ado when does it dispose? what happens when in the using i use a class member

Tags: ado.net

I have a porogram where I use m_sqlConnection as a class member 
does

```
  using (m_sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sr_ConnectionString))
   {
   m_sqlConnection.Open();
   } //dispose
```

similar to

```
 using ( SqlConnection m_sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sr_ConnectionString))
 {
              m_sqlConnection.Open();
 }//dispose
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both will dispose the new `SqlConnection`.

In the second case, trying to call any method on `m_sqlConnection` (if not re-assigned) will throw an exception.

See [`using Statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) on MSDN. There are several examples, including these cases.